# After adding DNS records for bluehost inside GoDaddy , my Office 365 email stop receiving emails

Tags: office-365, dns, hosting

I purchased a domain from Godaddy and i configured our Office 365 on the domain and the office 365 email addresses.

Last week i purchase a hosting from BlueHost and configure the Bluehost DNS records inside GoDaddy, to host our external website. after doing so, i can not send emails to our Office 365 emails, but i can send emails from.. any advice?
Thanks

Here is the error i will get when i send email to our office 365 emails:-

> Your message couldn't be delivered. It appears that the email address
> you sent your message to wasn't found at the destination domain, or
> the recipient's mailbox is unavailable. The email address might be
> misspelled or it might not exist. Try to fix the problem by doing one
> or more of the following: •   Send the message again. Before you do,
> delete and retype the complete address. If your email program
> automatically suggests an address to use don't select it.
>
> • Clear the recipient Auto-Complete List entry in your email program
> by following the steps in this article. Then resend the message, but
> before you do, delete and retype the complete address. If your email
> program suggests an address to use don't select it.
>
> • Contact the recipient by some other means (by phone, for example) to
> confirm you're using the right address. Ask them if they've set up an
> email forwarding rule that could be forwarding your message to an
> incorrect address. If you're still unable to fix the problem, ask the
> recipient to tell their email admin about the problem, and give them
> the server that reported the error below. For Email Admins When Office
> 365 tried to send the message, the external email server returned the
> error below. This error was reported by an email server outside Office
> 365, and if the sender is unable to fix the problem by correcting the
> recipient's email address or clearing the Auto-Complete List entry,
> then it's likely a problem that only the recipient's email admin can
> fix. •    Check the error for information about where the problem is
> happening. For example, look for a domain name. The domain name will
> tell you which organization was responsible for the error. The
> recipient's email server could be causing the problem, or it could be
> due to a third-party service that your organization or the recipient's
> organization is using to process or filter email messages.
>
> • If you can't fix the problem, contact the responsible party's email
> admin. This could be the recipient's email admin, your smart host
> service admin, or someone similar. Give them the error and the name of
> the server that reported the error to help them troubleshoot the
> issue. Unfortunately, Office 365 support is unlikely to be able to
> help with these kinds of externally reported errors.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't really related to SharePoint and we'd need more information to give you a definitive answer, but to me it sounds like your MX record is no longer pointing at Exchange Online. As a starting point, I'd suggest reviewing this Microsoft article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-at-godaddy?view=o365-worldwide

A very helpful tool to help with DNS troubleshooting is https://mxtoolbox.com

Comment: ok i defined this settings inside blueHost:- `Type` = `MX` + `Name`  = `mydomain.com` + `Destination` = `mydomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` .. but the TTL is disabled and set to `14400` while inside MS docs they mentioned to define the TTL as `3600`